# MSAF Google Analytics for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, google-analytics, windows-phone-7.1

I use MSAF Google Analytics for Windows Phone. I have configured it but it seems it does not work (I can not see any activity even 24h later)

I connected fiddler to WP emulator and there are some requests to GA servers, for example:

```
GET http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?AnalyticsVersion=4.3&utmn=794664447&utmhn=Windows%20Phone&utmni=1&utmt=event&utme=5(Login*Button%20tapped*From%20the%20Windows%20Phone%20App)(0)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmul=en&utmhid=987145401&utmac=UA-37521176-1&utmcc=__utma%3D1.98714540100145214523.1359035758.1359035758.1359035758.1359035759%3B%2B__utmz%3D1.1359035758.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B& HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: file:///Applications/Install/64AD5A45-B45E-4160-B9D4-145B47C7F131/Install/
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Tracker/1.0 (Windows Phone; 7.10.7720; Windows Phone)
Host: www.google-analytics.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And there is response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Via: 1.1 PGSRTR02
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 35
Age: 14844
Expires: Wed, 19 Apr 2000 11:43:00 GMT
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 09:48:43 GMT
Content-Type: image/gif
Server: GFE/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jan 2004 19:51:30 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate

GIF89a
```

I have tried some others frameworks - all them seem to send requests but i can not see any activity at Google analytics web-site

What is the point? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an account in Google Analytics as website not as app. Google Analytics doesn't support WP apps

Comment: i don't have reputation to add comment *****